# exec 2>&1 – execlude some command from being logged to file

Tags: bash, logging, scripting, redirection, command

I have the following in my bash script:

```
# catch input for log-data
exec > >(tee -i ${LOG})
exec 2>&1
```

I want to exclude one command from being written to this log file,
but the following doesn't work:

```
/sbin/runuser -l USER -c 'COMMAND' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It always gets logged to the `${LOG}` file. 
How can I prevent this?

Comment: (1) I tried what you say you tried, and the output from the distinguished command did not get written anywhere.  Please clarify what happens when you run it; perhaps giving *real* commands rather than the generic `command`.  (For example, ``date`` seems to write to stdout reliably; for stderr, use ``cat``, ``cp`` and ``ls`` with invalid arguments.)  (2) Your comment is wrong.  You are catching the *output* of subsequent commands, not the input.  (3) You should use ``"$LOG"`` (or ``"${LOG}"``, if you want) rather than ``${LOG}``.

Comment: I have updated, because of exec 2>&1 all errors get logged to the defined file, but i want for /sbin/runuser that the errors don't get logged to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out, my solution is:

Revert the exec command:

```
exec 1>&2 2>&-
```

Do the command

Restore the old exec:

```
exec 2>&1
```

If there are a better solution, you can tell me :)